# PHP curl - web scraping of page which requires login - sending via POST

Tags: php, authentication, curl, post, web-scraping

I have following simple web form called `login.php` which contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
  <meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off">
</head>
  <form action="action.php" method="post"> 
    <!-- Input: Input box -->
    Name:     <input name="userName" type="text"/>
    <br>
    Password: <input name="userPassword" type="password"/>
    <br>
    <!-- Submit form -->
    <input type="submit"/> <input type="reset"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have very simple file `action.php` which handles the data passed to it through `POST`, here is the code:

```
<?php
print_r ($_POST);
?>
```

This works perfectly and If I try to login as user `"foo"` and password `"bar"` I get:

```
Array ( [userName] => foo [userPassword] => bar )
```

What I want is to be able to send `POST` content via curl directly to `action.php` . So I have third file named `scraper.php` it's code is here:

```
<?php

// SLIGHTLY MODIFIED CODE FROM: http://www.phpcodester.com/2011/01/scraping-a-password-protected-website-with-curl/
$ch=login('http://localhost/scraper_post/action.php','userName=foo&userPassword=bar');
$html=downloadUrl('http://localhost/scraper_post/action.php', $ch);
echo $html;

function downloadUrl($Url, $ch){
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://localhost/scraper_post/login.php");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  return $output;
}

// ALSO TRIED WITH $postData ON SEPARATE LINES AS IT IS IN ORIGINAL TUTORIAL
function login($url,$postData){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  // ALSO TRIED WITH FOLLOWING, AS SUGGESTED IN ORIGINAL TUTORIAL COMMENTS: curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($postData));
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $store = curl_exec ($ch);
  return $ch;
}
?>
```

The problem is that when I call `scraper.php` I get the empty `$_POST` variable in `action.php` file. In other words `scraper.php` does not sends any `POST` data to `action.php` and I do not know why. This whole is just beginning for writing larger web scraper for page which requires login, but as you can see I am stuck right at the beginning. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `downloadUrl()` function, your `login()` function is already logging in and getting the contents. Do `return $store;` in `login()` and it will be the html from the site

My suggestion for the  code:

```
<?php

$html=login('http://localhost/scrapper_post/action.php','userName=foo&userPassword=bar');
echo $html;

function login($url,$postData){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://localhost/scrapper_post/login.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
?>
```